# can not implement this type of slider by slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to use slick slider, but how I understand Slick have not special setting to create that effect, when active image is over another with another's negative margin
This is the example in figma, is there any method to select z-index to center image, like here on image???
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to ask, how to apply formatting to the currently “active” slide? Surely it has a class for that.

Comment: yeah, but it is not absolute element to use z-index

Comment: z-index doesn’t need absolute, it needs _any_ position other than the default `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.slick-center` on `centerMode`.
A such:

```
.slick-active.slick-center {
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
}
```

```js
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
.center .slick-center h3 {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.08);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
    -o-transform: scale(1.08);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    border: 3px solid red;
    color: red;
    background: #fff;
}

.slick-active.slick-center {
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
}

.center h3 {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="slider center">
                <div>
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>3</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>4</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>5</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>6</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry where is blue element?

Comment: Not needed, that class or element.

Comment: really did not get it men)

Comment: What did you not get?

Comment: blue selector in css

Comment: There is no blue selector?

Comment: ooh okey men you removed it, sorry

Comment: :) understand now how to target the center element?

Comment: yeah, but I have a little problem with centering element, its not in center

Comment: You used ```centerMode``` and ```text-align:center;```?

Comment: https://ababken.github.io/projects/Persona/coloring.html look here

Comment: I got that,  on my page in github this site

Comment: You got fixed width set for those images, that's why. The image overflows its parent container pushing it to the right. Do some debugging which will make it work easily in the browser. Do also increase the ```scale``` value as in the example and apply some top and bottom ```padding``` to allow this element to show entirely. Make your images responsive. Hope this helps.